# recursive delete directory in z3

Tags: java, recursion, z3

I need to define a function in `z3` using java API that takes an directory an input and recursively deletes all its content. Since `z3` does not support recursive function, Is there any way to express such functionality?

Comment: You can use a stack and simulate recursion.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to convert recursion into iteration, you need to keep track of the state of the method in a stack. In this particular case the state is a file. So, the method goes something like this:

```
private void walkTreeUsingSimulation(Stack<File> stack) {
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        File f = stack.pop();
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        if(f.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                stack.push(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You create a stack by pushing the initial folder. In this case I am just printing the paths to the files. However, for you to able to remove the files, you want to traverse the leaf nodes first. The simplest might be to collect the whole into a list and use the list to remove the files.